# ZF2 Form: Customizing order of elements

Tags: php, forms, zend-framework2

I'm creating a form for a logged-in user to change their password, so I created a subclass of an existing password-reset form I have available.  The forms will be identical except with an additional field for existing password.  It's worked so far, except I can't figure out a way to manually set the order the new field; the only place I've gotten it to appear is at the end of the form. It seems that ZF2 requires you to `add()` form elements in the order that you want them rendered. I would do so, except the subclass form's constructor must the parent form's constructor before it can add new fields, by which point the parent form has already added its fields.

I have already tried setting the property `order` of my new field, but it did not work; I've tried several different combinations (I can't find the documentation for this feature anywhere, after lots of searching).

Subclass constructor snippet:

```
class ChangePassword extends ResetPassword implements InputFilterProviderInterface {

public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();

    $this->add(array(
        'type' => 'Zend\Form\Element\Password',
        'name' => 'existingPassword',
        'order' => 0,
        'options' => array(
            'label' => 'Existing Password',
            'order' => 0,
        ),
        'attributes' => array(
            'required' => 'required',
            'order' => 0,
        )
    ));
}
```

Parent constructor snippet:

```
class ResetPassword extends Form implements InputFilterProviderInterface {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct('reset-password');

        $this->add(array(
            'type' => 'Zend\Form\Element\Password',
            'name' => 'password',
            ...
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The key you're looking for which affects element order is named priority.

The form `add()` method accepts a second array containing `$flags`, and it's in this array that you must add the `priority` key/value pair.

Your constructor should end up looking something like this ...

```
class ChangePassword extends ResetPassword implements InputFilterProviderInterface {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();

        $this->add(array(
            'type' => 'Zend\Form\Element\Password',
            'name' => 'existingPassword',
            'options' => array(
                'label' => 'Existing Password',
            ),
            'attributes' => array(
                'required' => 'required',
            )
        ), // add flags array containing priority key/value 
        array(
            'priority' => 1000, // Increase value to move to top of form
        ));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick! I had to change the priority to something higher though; I edited your answer to reflect that. If you found this somewhere in the docs please post a link if you don't mind :)

Comment: I actually found it by (shock horror!) reading the code. The `Form` class extends the `Fieldset` class and the forms `add()` method calls its parent method. Following that back and checking the method you find these lines -> https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/master/library/Zend/Form/Fieldset.php#L187-L189

Answer (score 0):

I have encouter this issue today, Crisp's answer helped but I think it would be nice to precise this :

In the view we have a lot of options to show our form :

> - `<?= $this->form($form)?>`
> - `<?= $form->get('{element}') ?>`
> - loop over `$form->getIterator()`
> - loop over `$form->getElements()`

etc...

I have to say i used a lot this structure in all of my projects :

```
<?php foreach ($form->get('fieldset')->getElements()  as $elementName => $element): ?>
     <?= $this->partial('partial/formElement', ['element' => $element])?>
<?php endforeach ?>
```

The problem is : getElements does not use priority, so its just give the element in order of when it was instanciated.

In the view we have to use the iteration method (`$form->getIterator()`) to get back this flag priority.