# zf2 TwbBundle button group inside fieldset

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap-3, zend-framework2

I am working with zf2 and the TwbBundle. I wanto to add two buttons as a button group to the end of various forms. When I directly add them to the Form as two objects with the button-group option set, then it is rendered fine.

```
$this->add(array(
    'name' => 'submit',
    'type' => 'Button',
    'options' => array(
        'label' => 'Speichern',
        'button-group' => 'group-1',
    ),
    'attributes' => array(
        'type' => 'submit',
        'class' => 'btn btn-primary btn-lg',
    ),
));

$this->add(array(
     'name' => 'cancel',
     'type' => 'Button',
     'options' => array(
         'label' => 'Abbrechen',
         'button-group' => 'group-1',
     ),
    'attributes' => array(
         'type' => 'submit',
         'class' => 'btn btn-default btn-lg',
    ),
));
```

This results in:

```
<div class="form-group ">
    <div class="btn-group">
        <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" value="">Speichern</button>
        <button type="submit" name="cancel" class="btn btn-default btn-lg" value="">Abbrechen</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

But once I extract them into a reusable fieldset each of the elements gets wrapped in its own form-group element and no longer renders as a button group.

```
<fieldset>
    <div class="form-group ">
        <button type="submit" name="form-controls[submit]" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" value="">Speichern</button>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group ">
        <button type="submit" name="form-controls[cancel]" class="btn btn-default btn-lg" value="">Abbrechen</button>
    </div>
</fieldset>
```

I tried adding css classes or button-group options to the fieldset in the form class, but nothing had the desired effect.

Anyone had the same problem or might have an idea on how to realize this?

Cheers
Jens

Edit: On request additional code. How the fieldset is defined:

```
<?php
namespace Application\Form;

use Zend\Form\Fieldset;

class FormControls extends Fieldset
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct('form-controls');

        $this->add(array(
            'name' => 'submit',
            'type' => 'Button',
            'options' => array(
                'label' => 'Speichern',
                'button-group' => 'group-1',
            ),
            'attributes' => array(
                'type' => 'submit',
                'class' => 'btn btn-primary btn-lg',
            ),
        ));

        $this->add(array(
            'name' => 'cancel',
            'type' => 'Button',
            'options' => array(
                'label' => 'Abbrechen',
                'button-group' => 'group-1',
            ),
            'attributes' => array(
                'type' => 'submit',
                'class' => 'btn btn-default btn-lg',
            ),
        ));
    }
}
```

And included with this:

```
$this->add(array(
    'name' => 'form-controls',
    'type' => 'Application\Form\FormControls',
));
```

Comment: Could you post how you use your reusable fieldset? Do you extend a class or do you add the fieldset to another fieldset?

Comment: edited the question with additional code. For the fieldset I extend on the Fieldset class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you are getting the extra fieldset tag is, because you are adding your elements via a fieldset.

> class FormControls extends Fieldset

```
$this->add(array(
    'name' => 'form-controls',
    'type' => 'Application\Form\FormControls',
));
```

The solution would be to have the (form/fieldset) class which adds:

```
$this->add(array(
    'name' => 'form-controls',
    'type' => 'Application\Form\FormControls',
));
```

To extend a (form/fieldset) class containing:

```
$this->add(array(
    'name' => 'submit',
    'type' => 'Button',
    'options' => array(
        'label' => 'Speichern',
        'button-group' => 'group-1',
    ),
    'attributes' => array(
        'type' => 'submit',
        'class' => 'btn btn-primary btn-lg',
    ),
));

$this->add(array(
     'name' => 'cancel',
     'type' => 'Button',
     'options' => array(
         'label' => 'Abbrechen',
         'button-group' => 'group-1',
    ),
    'attributes' => array(
         'type' => 'submit',
         'class' => 'btn btn-default btn-lg',
    ),
));
```

So you can have your reusable buttons. The result would be a structure like: **CoolForm** extends **ButtonForm** extends **Form**, in which:

- **Form** would be the Zend class
- **ButtonForm** is the class defining and adding the buttons
- **CoolForm** is the form actually userd, which inherits the buttons without the fieldset wrapping them

Comment: Thanks, this works. I now have my two buttons displayed the way they are supposed to. Though as I extend on my **ButtonForm** class, they are always on the very top of my forms. I checked this question, but the priority flag does not seem to work for me (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25811923/zf2-form-customizing-order-of-elements). Any idea how I can force them to the very bottom?

Comment: You should call the parent function, that adds the buttons, after you add your other elements.

Comment: Thank you so much. Works like a charm.